# How Can i add html file in function of javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

When I click on button, add `html` file on page.

```
<script>
  function speech()
   {
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#Button").click(function() {
    window.location.assign("/Integration Demo File/voice.html");
    })
  })
} 
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to replace an element of HTML with file content voice.html then try this

```
$("#myDiv").load("/path/to/file/voice.html")
```